# Manage package error for after Update Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, community, managed-package

I wrote trigger **for changing contact owner when account owner changes** as below

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (after update) {
    Set<Id> accountId = new Set<Id>();    
    List<Contact> contactsToUpdate = new List<Contact>();

    for (Account objAccount : Trigger.new){
        if (objAccount.OwnerId != Trigger.oldMap.get(objAccount.Id).OwnerId){  
            accountId.add(objAccount.Id);
        }        
    }

    if (!accountId.isEmpty()) {
        for (Account objAccount : [SELECT Id,OwnerId , (SELECT Id, OwnerId FROM Contacts WHERE Owner.isActive=True) FROM Account WHERE Id in :accountId]){                 
            for (Contact objContact : objAccount.Contacts){                
                objContact.ownerId = objAccount.OwnerId;
                contactsToUpdate.add(objContact);                
            }            
        }
    }
    if(contactsToUpdate.size()>0){
        update contactsToUpdate;
    }
}
```

It's working fine but for some contact it is giving manage package error such as

> "Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 0036F00001s7DtZQAU;
>   first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, MC4SF.Contact:
>   execution of AfterUpdate" where MC4SF is manage package.

How to avoid this
Thank you!!

Comment: If the managed package is not really being used just uninstall it. Otherwise you will need to contact the managed package supplier. They may have a mechanism to switch their trigger/triggers off and on or you may need to work with them to figure out the problem and agree a solution on their side or your side.

Comment: The first reviewer here isn't a fan of this managed package https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B3byfEAB&revId=a0S3000000ITxsuEAD&tab=r. Lots of other bad reviews too.